# Appcelerator titanium Mobile Module Project?

Tags: module, appcelerator-mobile

In Appcelerator Titanium to create a Mobile Module Project I am using titanium 1.8.2
and selected Mobile module Project and gave projectname & Appid  but it shows message like "Target platform(s) not selected (Missing required Android Add-Ons[addon.+google.+apis.+7, addon.+google.+apis.+8])".Anybody know What should do

Answer (score 0):

Launch the Android SDK Manager that is packaged in the Android SDK installer, and select the packages that need to be installed.

Comment: oh i should install Addon API 7 & 8 right Danny.Thank u for quick reply

Comment: Yes, you could go ahead and install all the add-ons but some require third party accounts and it could take a while to download them all.